# Python 2.7 Beautiful Soup Img Src Extract

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
for imgsrc in Soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'sizedProdImage'}):
    if imgsrc:
        imgsrc = imgsrc
    else:
        imgsrc = "ERROR"

patImgSrc = re.compile('src="(.*)".*/>')
findPatImgSrc = re.findall(patImgSrc, imgsrc)

print findPatImgSrc

'''
<img height="72" name="proimg" id="image" class="sizedProdImage" src="http://imagelocation" />
```

This is what I am trying to extract from and I am getting:

```
findimgsrcPat = re.findall(imgsrcPat, imgsrc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

'''

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're passing beautifulsoup node to re.findall. You have to convert it to string. Try:

```
findPatImgSrc = re.findall(patImgSrc, str(imgsrc))
```

Better yet, use the tools beautifulsoup provides:

```
[x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'sizedProdImage'})]
```

gives you a list of all src attributes of img tags of class 'sizedProdImage'.

Answer (score 43):

There is more simple solution:

```
 soup.find('img')['src']
```

Comment: 5 years later and this is still the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an `re` object, then passing it into `re.findall` which expects a string as the first argument:

```
patImgSrc = re.compile('src="(.*)".*/>')
findPatImgSrc = re.findall(patImgSrc, imgsrc)
```

Instead, use the `.findall` method of the patImgSrc object you just created:

```
patImgSrc = re.compile('src="(.*)".*/>')
findPatImgSrc = patImgSrc.findall(imgsrc)
```

Comment: Still getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BuyzDirect\Desktop\OverStock_Listing_Format_Tool.py", line 50, in <module>
    findPatImgSrc = patImgSrc.findall(imgsrc)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

In my example, the htmlText contains the img tag but it can be used for a URL too. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup/47166671#47166671)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
htmlText = """<img src="https://src1.com/" <img src="https://src2.com/" /> """
soup = BSHTML(htmlText)
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print image['src']
```