# Extract the 'src' attribute from an 'img' tag using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Consider:

```html
<div class="someClass">
    <a href="href">
        <img alt="some" src="some"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to extract the source (i.e., *src*) attribute from an image (i.e., *img*) tag using Beautiful Soup. I use Beautiful Soup 4, and I cannot use `a.attrs['src']` to get the `src`, but I can get `href`. What should I do?

Comment: Why would you expect `a.attrs['src']` to work?  There's no `<a>` tag with a `src` attribute in the snippet you've shown.

Comment: this is also a completely different question than before & the headline makes no sense now.

Comment: @patrick I used regex to get the `src` .what's the other questions ?

Comment: @jwodder I see that later but when I use `img.attrs['src']` it also got wrong . but later I used regex to get what i want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Beautifulsoup img tag parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600079/python-beautifulsoup-img-tag-parsing)

Answer (score 98):

You can use Beautiful Soup to extract the *src* attribute of an HTML `img` tag. In my example, the `htmlText` contains the `img` tag itself, but this can be used for a URL too, along with `urllib2`.

**For URLs**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/')
soup = BSHTML(page)
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    # Print image source
    print(image['src'])
    # Print alternate text
    print(image['alt'])
```

**For texts with the img tag**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
htmlText = """<img src="https://src1.com/" <img src="https://src2.com/" /> """
soup = BSHTML(htmlText)
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print(image['src'])
```

**Python 3:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import urllib

page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com/abushoeb/emotag')
soup = BSHTML(page)
images = soup.findAll('img')

for image in images:
    # Print image source
    print(image['src'])
    # Print alternate text
    print(image['alt'])
```

**Install modules if needed**

```
# Python 3
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install urllib3
```

Comment: How can I extract image title from img tag with id="my_img", only one specific image

Comment: Since `ID` is not a default attribute of the `image` tag, you can't get anything like `image['id']`. However, if you print the `image` value you'll see all attributes and values. Perhaps you can then tokenize it and find your desired image with the id you are looking for.

Comment: On some systems, e.g. some versions of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), the name of the executable is `pip3` (for Python 3, and as the only (default) option), not `pip`.

Answer (score 20):

A link doesn't have attribute `src`. You have to target the actual `img` tag.

```
import bs4

html = """<div class="someClass">
    <a href="href">
        <img alt="some" src="some"/>
    </a>
</div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# this will return src attrib from img tag that is inside 'a' tag
soup.a.img['src']

>>> 'some'

# if you have more then one 'a' tag
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.img:
        print(a.img['src'])

>>> 'some'
```

Answer (score 8):

> You can use Beautiful Soup to extract the *src* attribute of an HTML `img` tag. In my example, the `htmlText` contains the `img` tag itself, but this can be used for a URL too, along with `urllib2`.

The solution provided by the [Abu Shoeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-the-src-attribute-from-an-img-tag-using-beautiful-soup/47166671#47166671) is not working any more with Python 3. This is the correct implementation:

**For URLs**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'your_url'

response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BSHTML(response.data, "html.parser")
images = soup.findAll('img')

for image in images:
    # Print image source
    print(image['src'])
    # Print alternate text
    print(image['alt'])
```

**For texts with the 'img' tag**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
htmlText = """<img src="https://src1.com/" <img src="https://src2.com/" /> """
soup = BSHTML(htmlText)
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print(image['src'])
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that will not trigger a KeyError in case the *img* tag does not have a *src* attribute:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "[insert name of the site]"
html = urlopen(site)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

images = bs.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src'):
        print(img['src'])
```

Comment: Re *"KeyError"*: Is an exception thrown?