# Beautiful Soup leaves out tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse an HTML file with python, but BeautifulSoup leaves out some key tags.

The part of the HTML file on the website  looks like this, with all of the children divs. 
[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XhTQ.png)

But when using the beautifulsoup prettify function, it looks like this, without any of the children divs. 
[HTML snippet from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfvTx.png)

The code I used is here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

#A random plus code, the %2B is  just a +

PLUS_CODE = "792F7C4F%2B54"
url = "https://www.plus.codes/" + PLUS_CODE

hdr = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
r_tags = r.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_tags, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())
```

What ends up happening is that I can't reach the children div and extract the text that I need.

Comment: How are you reading and parsing it?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us [*some* of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you used so that it would be easier for us to help you figure out the problem..

Comment: Actually, my code was just  the printing the prettify function, to see why I couldn't  access one of the children tags.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `'lxml'` instead of `'html.parser'` in the BeautifulSoup method. Maybe that will solve the problem. If not, share some code.

Comment: Yeah the same thing happens.

Comment: Maybe the HTML file needs to be "cleaned". You are not web scraping, right?

Comment: Actually, I am web scraping

Comment: The tags you are trying to find might be hidden in JavaScript. Give me the url, so I can check.

Comment: https://www.plus.codes/792F7C4F+54  The  part in question is in the body, and is maybe  the fifth div tag there

Comment: Ye almost the whole page is JavaScript rendered. BeautifulSoup will never work here. You need Selenium