# How do I scrape image-src in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get image-src in this code:

```
<img alt='Original Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 4GB RAM 64GB ROM Snapdragon S636 Octa Core Mobile Phone MIUI9 5.99" 2160*1080 4000mAh 12.0+5.0MP(China)' class="picCore" id="limage_32856997152" image-src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1WDJZbE_rK1Rjy0Fcq6zEvVXaS/Original-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-Snapdragon-S636-Octa-Core-Mobile-Phone-MIUI9.jpg_220x220xz.jpg" itemprop="image"/>
```

I tried this code but it is not working:

> images = soup.find('img').get('image-src')

Usually I use `get('src')` and it works but the problem is here: I need to use image-src which does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract \`src\` attribute from \`img\` tag using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) documentation, I found the `find_all` method which works for this case:

This worked for me:

```
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('image-src'))
```

Here was my full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<img alt='Original Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 4GB RAM 64GB ROM Snapdragon S636 Octa Core Mobile Phone MIUI9 5.99" 2160*1080 4000mAh 12.0+5.0MP(China)' class="picCore" id="limage_32856997152" image-src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1WDJZbE_rK1Rjy0Fcq6zEvVXaS/Original-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-Snapdragon-S636-Octa-Core-Mobile-Phone-MIUI9.jpg_220x220xz.jpg" itemprop="image"/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('image-src'))
```

and the result:

```
//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1WDJZbE_rK1Rjy0Fcq6zEvVXaS/Original-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-Snapdragon-S636-Octa-Core-Mobile-Phone-MIUI9.jpg_220x220xz.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary. You can access that dictionary directly as `.attrs`

```
soup.find('img').attrs['image-src']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an css id selector if the id is static to select the element then subset to get the img-src attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<img alt='Original Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 4GB RAM 64GB ROM Snapdragon S636 Octa Core Mobile Phone MIUI9 5.99" 2160*1080 4000mAh 12.0+5.0MP(China)' class="picCore" id="limage_32856997152" image-src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1WDJZbE_rK1Rjy0Fcq6zEvVXaS/Original-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-Snapdragon-S636-Octa-Core-Mobile-Phone-MIUI9.jpg_220x220xz.jpg" itemprop="image"/>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#limage_32856997152')['image-src'])
```

---

If id is not static, and if there can be more than one to target you might want to use a class selector combined with attribute

```
srcs = [ img['image-src'] for img in soup.select('.picCore[image-src]')]
print(srcs)
```

Any image-src, just use an attribute selector

```
srcs = [img['image-src'] for img in soup.select('[image-src]')]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna take the src you can do this...

```
new_var = soup.find(attrs={"attribute" : "name_attr"})
imageItem= new_var.get('src')
```