# Find with regex and get value from img tag which is member of another tag

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I have code from website, where I would like to find and get path to image, I mean value from `src` in `img` tag. Core of the issue are paths to images between tags: `wphimage` and with `.jpg` extensions.

Below the code:

```
<p>
    <wphimage data="{'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong'}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="John Smith"  class="lightview" href="//path/to/image/web.jpg"">
            <img src="//path/to/image/web.jpg" alt="Name">
        </a>
        <a class="A_copyright" href="javascript:;">©&nbsp; <span>Terry Linke</span></a>
        <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>| 
        <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//path/to/image/web.jpg" data-lightview-title="Dietfried Gürtler" data-lightview-caption="Terry Linke">+ </a>
    </span>
    </wphimage>

    Text here...
</p>
```

I tried with:

```
wphimage = re.findall(r'\S+\.jpg', text)
```

but I got also another values, from different tags then `<img>`.

Comment: Use beautifulsoup as mentioned there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
wphimage = re.findall(r'<img.*src=\"(\S*|\w*)\"', txt)
```

output

```
['//path/to/image/web.jpg']
```

This regex is getting any non-whitespace and any word characters that between " " in an img tag src value.