# how to find link with select_one in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
image = soup.select_one('#productImage > li > a > span > img')
print(image)

<img alt="Image" src="https://cdn.cloudflare.com/image.jpg" title="Image"/>
```

I would like to print like this:

```
https://cdn.cloudflare.com/image.jpg
```

Thank you for your answers guys

HTML:

```
<span class="imgInner">
<img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.com/image.jpg" alt="image" title="image">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup/47166671) post.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<span class="imgInner">
<img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.com/image.jpg" alt="image" title="image">
</span>""", 'lxml')
image = soup.select_one('span.imgInner img')['src']
print(image)
```