# How to extract SRC attribute from IMG tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the code I obtain with `BS4` and I succeed to write in a CSV

```py
[<div class="clearfix hide-mobile" id="image-block"><span id="view_full_size"><span class="product_game-language"><svg class="svg-flag_en icon"><use xlink:href="#svg-flag_en"></use></svg></span><span class="ratio-container" style="max-width:372px"><img alt="Dominion - Plunder" height="372" id="bigpic" itemprop="image" loading="lazy" src="https://imageotoget.jpg" width="372"/></span></span></div>]
```

How can I get only the SRC attribute and not the entire tags text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the 'src' attribute from an 'img' tag using Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-the-src-attribute-from-an-img-tag-using-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="clearfix hide-mobile" id="image-block"><span id="view_full_size"><span class="product_game-language"><svg class="svg-flag_en icon"><use xlink:href="#svg-flag_en"></use></svg></span><span class="ratio-container" style="max-width:372px"><img alt="Dominion - Plunder" height="372" id="bigpic" itemprop="image" loading="lazy" src="https://imageotoget.jpg" width="372"/></span></span></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

element = soup.select_one('img')
src = element.attrs['src']
print(src)
```

or as @Ahmed Mohamedeen said

```
src = element['src']
```

result is the same

```
https://imageotoget.jpg
```